# Adding audio files to Android resources

Tags: android

I added a few mp3 files (eg, bells.mp3) to a 'raw' folder under 'res'. However, when I do this:

mp = MediaPlayer(this,R.raw.bells);

it complains that 'raw' cannot be resolved. Is there something more I need to do to make these resources available?

Comment: Did you clean your project to make sure Eclipse detects the new files?

Comment: Make sure the file name contains to invalid characters. Android resources must not contain multiple dots or upper case letters.

Comment: Thanks. I had to restart Eclipse. I am **always** forgetting to do this! *When will I ever learn??*

Answer (score 3):

Please make sure that you are importing R from your project not the android one

Example:

```
import com.example.myProject.R;
```

not this one

```
import android.R;
```

Answer (score -3):

In `gen > com.projectName` there is the `R.java` file which is generated when you add items to the `res` folder. You can ensure and manually add ids here, despite the warning. This worked fine for me when adding assets outside of the eclipse ide. I would just add a new `name=0XWHATEVER+1` to the appropriate class and it would work fine.

Comment: Not a good idea, this file will be deleted and recreated by the tools when you clean the project. In fact cleaning the project is what you should be doing to have your resources appear in this file. Beware of errors in your project as they might prevent this file from being recreated properly.